# Need to write MySQL case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I need to write a MySQL statement, but not sure how to write it using case statements.

I would like to write something like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
    FROM 
        table 
    WHERE:

        IF sign_off_1 IS NOT NULL AND sign_off_1 IS NOT EQUAL TO 'Director' 
        sign_off_1_status MUST BE EQUAL TO Complete

        IF sign_off_2 IS NOT NULL AND sign_off_2 IS NOT EQUAL TO 'Director' 
        sign_off_2_status MUST BE EQUAL TO Complete

        IF sign_off_3 is IS NOT NULL AND sign_off_3 IS NOT EQUAL TO 
        'Director' sign_off_3_status MUST BE EQUAL TO Complete
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax to write this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to achieve. Does a row need to satisfy all three conditions, or just one of them? Either result can be achieved without using `CASE` expressions.

If the requirement is to use `CASE` expressions, and you need all three conditions to be true, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE CASE 
         WHEN t.sign_off_1 <> 'Director' AND t.sign_off_1_status = 'Complete'
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
     + CASE 
         WHEN t.sign_off_2 <> 'Director' AND t.sign_off_2_status = 'Complete'
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
     + CASE 
         WHEN t.sign_off_3 <> 'Director' AND t.sign_off_3_status = 'Complete'
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
     = 3
```

If you only need one of the conditions to be true, you could replace `= 3` with `> 0`.

Note that an inequality comparison to a literal is sufficient to guarantee the column is not null. (If the column is NULL, the inequality comparison will return NULL, rather than TRUE.)

Again, the same result could be achieved without using `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OR` and `AND` operator to simulate `if` condition in `where` clause. Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  ( sign_off_1 <> 'Director'
         AND sign_off_1_status = 'Complete' )
        OR ( sign_off_2 <> 'Director'
             AND sign_off_2_status = 'Complete' )
        OR ( sign_off_3 <> 'Director'
             AND sign_off_3_status = 'Complete' ) 
        OR ( sign_off <> 'Director' 
             AND status <> 'Complete')
```

**Update:** am not completely sure about your comment. But this is what i understood.

```
WHERE  (( sign_off_1 <> 'Director'
         AND sign_off_1_status = 'Complete' )
        OR ( sign_off_2 <> 'Director'
             AND sign_off_2_status = 'Complete' )
        OR ( sign_off_3 <> 'Director'
             AND sign_off_3_status = 'Complete' )) 
        AND ( sign_off <> 'Director' 
             AND status <> 'Complete')
```

Comment: The `IS NOT NULL` predicates are redundant; the inequality comparison is sufficient to guarantee that the column is not null.

Comment: Thanks - it works, but not exactly as required.  This is a fault on my part for not mentioning that it also should not select rows where the sign_off is equal to 'Director' and the status is eqal to 'Complete'.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @BradleyE - updated. But am not sure is this what you need. Update your question with the previous comment

Comment: @BradleyE - Added another option